# How to calculate percentage from excel with javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, math, percentage

I have a cell (G28) on Excel with the value 439.
I have another cell that calculates this: (G28/(100%-12%-15%))*12%
The result in Excel is 72.
I'm trying to reproduce the same calculation in javascript.

Thats my code so far:

```
    var total_net_area = 439;
    var result = Math.round((total_net_area/(total_net_area-(total_net_area/100*12)-(total_net_area/100*15)))*1.12;
    console.log(result);
```

The expected result should be 72, but is not what I'm getting on javascript.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(G28/(100%-12%-15%))*12%`

When doing conversions from Excel, one idea is to do exactly the same.  You can always re-arrange later. Things like g28, why not make your variable g28, and later when everything is working as expect, rename etc.   For a simple formula like yours it's maybe overkill, but when converting large excel spreadsheet formula's that's what I tend to do.

Now `12%`, let just make a simple function here, yes you could just divide by 100 inline, as that's what percent means,  `per / cent`.   But to keep as near to Excel as possible a simple function would be handy..

```
const pc = c => c / 100;
```

So putting all together.

```js
const G28 = 439;

const pc = c => c / 100;

const result = (G28 / (pc(100) - pc(12) - pc(15))) * pc(12);

console.log(result);
```

Once you know it's working as expected, now think about changing say G28 into `total_net_area` etc, this multi-pass type of programming might seem overkill, but you might be surprised how it prevents silly errors.  Like as pointed out in the other comments,  1.12 (112%) is not the same as 0.12 (12%)